# How to subtract date between two values if both value is not NULL In RDLC

Tags: vb.net, rdlc

This is my current code/expression to subtract the both value:

```
=RIGHT ( Left( (fields!I.value - fields!O.value).ToString(), (fields!I.value - fields!O.value).ToString().Length - (fields!I.value - fields!O.value).ToString().LastIndexOf(".")), 8)
```

But if either of them is null, the expression is still going on, resulting like in the image below, In total hours column

[I just want the total hours column has value if Clock in and clock out is not NULL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50grN.jpg)

I.value=clock in

o.value=clock Out

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `IsNothing()` function to check if the fields have values. 
 Another great function to know in SSRS is the `IIF` statement. This allows you to to have different outputs depending on an expression. Just like your standard if-else block.

Here is a little example that hopefully explains it a little:

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!I.Value) OR IsNothing(Fields!O.Value), "One of the fields NULL" , "Both fields have values")
```

Below is the one you'll actually want to use (I haven't tested it, but if your formula is correct then this should work.)

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!I.Value) OR IsNothing(Fields!O.Value), "" , RIGHT( Left( (fields!I.value - fields!O.value).ToString(), (fields!I.value - fields!O.value).ToString().Length - (fields!I.value - fields!O.value).ToString().LastIndexOf(".")), 8))
```

You should consider having a nice read trough the following documentation :[Expression Examples (Report Builder and SSRS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/expression-examples-report-builder-and-ssrs)